# How to launch google-chrome with custom parameters by default?

Tags: google-chrome, settings, ram

I want to launch chrome and chromium from the unity launcher with the `--purge-memory-button` option.

For chromium I was able to add the above parameter to `/etc/chromium-browser/default` but that's not an option for `google-chrome`.

How do I do it for `google-chrome` ? Would an alias in my `.bash_profile` work ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Edit the .desktop file in

```
/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
```

Edit the exec line and add the arguments you need

Comment: The .desktop file might get reverted on your next chrome update. So it might be a good idea to copy it to `~/.local/share/applications`.

Comment: @Glutanimate is it necessary to copy the whole file? Or if I just create a `~/.local/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop` and put something like `[Desktop Entry]\nExec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable ...`, will it "inherit" all the other bits from the `/usr/share/applications` one? https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/669929/550426 seems to imply no, but I just want to be sure.